# Declare variable inside function based on environment detection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to change "var $siteURL" & data "SITE: value".

If desktop environment, change code to "DES001". Otherwise if its mobile environment, change code to "MOB001".

By default, desktop siteURL and site data value works fine.

**JS:**

```
var $siteCode = 'DES001';

if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  alert("Mobile Device");
  var $siteCode = 'MOB001';
}

$('#SubmitForm').click(function() { 
  var $linkURL = 'http://www.test.com/SITE=',
      $siteURL = $siteCode,
      $webServiceURL = $linkURL + $siteURL;

  var $data = { 
    ARRANGE: 'DDD',
    BOOKING: 'CASH',
    SITE: $siteCode,
  }

 var $tripFlowUrl = $webServiceURL + $.param($data);
 alert($tripFlowUrl);
});
```

Comment: Hi @David.. Mobile detection is working for me.. Please let me know how to change SiteURL & Site data value based on detection. Thats the only thing pending for me

Comment: The entire question seems to focus heavily on mobile detection.  Best to remove the unrelated things and focus specifically on the problem at hand, which is setting and using a variable in and out of an `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring your variable in the wrong scope:

```
if (/.../) {
    var $mobileSiteCode = '';
}

// can't use $mobileSiteCode here, it's out of scope
```

Declare the variable in the scope you need it, then simply set the value within the conditional statement:

```
var $mobileSiteCode = '';
if (/.../) {
    $mobileSiteCode = 'some value';
}

// now you can use $mobileSiteCode here
```

Comment: Hi David.. Thanks for your help. But, now can i change this $mobilesiteCode or $desktopsiteCode values dynamically on click function & data value? This is the solution i am looking for. Thanks. Very sorry to trouble you.

Comment: @TDG: You can change the values anywhere that you can access the values.  The code in the question may be a bit incomplete for what you're asking now.  But as long as the variables are in scope you can modify them.  Do you have a minimal example of something that isn't working?

Comment: i change my above codes like you mentioned. Now, even desktop or mobile, it shows only "DES001". even in mobile environment, its not getting "MOB001"

Comment: @TDG: When you debug this, where specifically does it fail?  Given the code and the description in your last comment, it sounds like the `if` statement isn't resolving to `true`, though you'd previously claimed that the mobile browser detection was working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. finally i fixed the issue. Please check my below code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 console.log("Mobile Device");
 var $siteCode = 'MOB001';
}
else{
 console.log("Desktop Device");
 var $siteCode = 'DES001';
}

function submitForm(){
 $('#SubmitForm').click(function() { 
  var $linkURL = 'http://www.test.com/SITE=',
      $siteURL = $siteCode,
      $webServiceURL = $linkURL + $siteURL;

  var $data = { 
   ARRANGE: 'DDD',
   BOOKING: 'CASH',
   SITE: $siteCode,
  }

  var $tripFlowUrl = $webServiceURL + $.param($data);
  alert($tripFlowUrl);
 });
}
```